# Php self table join on timestamp

Tags: php, html, mysql, join

I have a single SQL table running in my db where all my device in the field report too.

Some event written in it are time base, other are async, that why some entry have the same time stamp ( ts )

This is the table ( name is: data )

```
id     node_id  type    origin  value   ts  
54475   11      COV     P1      2969    2017-04-30  21:54:59    
54476   11      COV     P1      2967    2017-04-30  21:56:16    
54477   11      INT     P1      2967    2017-04-30  22:00:00    
54478   11      INT     P4      2297    2017-04-30  22:00:00    
54479   11      COV     P1      2965    2017-04-30  22:08:00    
54480   11      INT     P1      2966    2017-04-30  22:15:01    
54481   11      INT     P4      2301    2017-04-30  22:15:01    
54482   11      INT     P1      2963    2017-04-30  22:30:03    
54483   11      INT     P4      2299    2017-04-30  22:30:03    
54484   11      COV     P1      2961    2017-04-30  22:35:00    
54485   11      COV     P1      2963    2017-04-30  22:43:40
```

I'd like to have my sql request giving me an output like this

```
type    P1     P2     P3    P4    device_ts
COV    2969                       2017-04-30  21:54:59
COV    2967                       2017-04-30  21:56:16
INT    2967                 2297  2017-04-30  22:00:00
COV    2965                       2017-04-30  22:08:00
INT    2966                 2301  2017-04-30  22:15:01
INT    2963                 2299  2017-04-30  22:30:03
COV    2961                       2017-04-30  22:35:00
COV    2963                       2017-04-30  22:43:40
```

so I'll be able to do something like this in my html code

```
while($data = $P1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if($data['type']=="INT")
    {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>P1 value is : ".$data['P1']."</td>";
      echo "<td>P2 value is : ".$data['P2']."</td>";
      echo "<td>P3 value is : ".$data['P3']."</td>";
      echo "<td>P4 value is : ".$data['P4']."</td>";
      echo "<td>Time stamp. : ".$data['device_ts']."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Is that something possible? What would be the sql request format?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the heavy lifting for this query directly in MySQL using the following pivot query:

```
SELECT
    type,
    MAX(CASE WHEN origin = 'P1' THEN value END) AS P1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN origin = 'P2' THEN value END) AS P2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN origin = 'P3' THEN value END) AS P3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN origin = 'P4' THEN value END) AS P4,
    device_ts
FROM data
GROUP BY type, device_ts
ORDER BY device_ts, type
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Are you saying this Is a complicated request for my database, will it be a problem when I'll have 25 millions entry in the table?

Comment: @Jean-GabrielMaurice I would be more worried about having a very large, unknown number, of columns to pivot.  If you really only have four `P` values then I would rather handle this problem in the database.

Comment: Its not working, I'm not getting any value of that request

Comment: @Jean-GabrielMaurice Reload the page, I had a typo, this is why I setup the demo.

Comment: "Connection failed: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ts' in 'field list'"

Comment: You told us in your question that there is a column called `ts` for the timestamp.  If it's really called `device_ts`, or something else, then it's on you to provide accurate information to us so we can write an accurate query.  The demo works, and you should easily be able to adapt it for your own needs.

Comment: Yes you are right, I've made a mistake, in my data table the 'ts' is 'device_ts' also, my apologies

Comment: I ended up with.  $sql = "SELECT
    type,value,device_ts,node_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN origin = 'P1' THEN value END) AS P1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN origin = 'P2' THEN value END) AS P2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN origin = 'P3' THEN value END) AS P3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN origin = 'P4' THEN value END) AS P4,
    device_ts AS ts
 FROM data
 WHERE type ='INT'
 AND node_id = '$nodeid'
 GROUP BY type, device_ts
 ORDER BY device_ts
 ";

Comment: Your query has a problem, because you are selecting `value` but it doesn't appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: ok, so each value selected must be in the group by clause? that is mandatory?